# how do you run a php file on a chromebook?

Tags: php, chromebook

I've been looking on YouTube and other places, i'm not sure how, this place is filled with smart people so i thought i would ask you guys!

Comment: Through a local web server, or command line?

Comment: Visit the link?

Comment: @symlink — And how do you get those on a Chromebook?

Comment: @luekbaja — What link?

Comment: I don't think you are able to run PHP files directly from a Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-a-chromebook-for-web-development) lists some options:

- Termux lets you install a Linux environment and [has a PHP distribution](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/php) (but it is highly restricted and you will probably run into plenty of frustrating limits)
- You can enable Developer Mode and then press Ctrl-Alt-T to open a crosh shell, from which you get type `shell` to get a regular shell and from there either:

  - Install Linux and dual-boot
  - Create a chroot environment to develop in

Meanwhile [OS 69](https://9to5google.com/2018/09/18/google-chrome-os-69-stable-release/) introduces [Linux for Chromebook](https://9to5google.com/2018/05/08/chrome-os-linux-app-support/) which should be an easier way to get a Linux environment.

… but that said, Chromebooks are generally low-powered machines that aren't ideal hardware for doing development work. I'd look at setting up a remote server and doing my dev work over SSH.

Comment: thank you for the link, im using my Chromebook for some low level websites witch im trying to develop. nothing to complex for my Chromebook.

Comment: I wouldn't use an OS with version 69!  69 sounds a bit dirty.  I could be a hacker's plaything.

Comment: You could use a desktop workstation with XAMPP and give your chrome OS access, if you don't have funding or access to online hosting.  Amazon's AWT is easy to setup and costs very little unless someone hacks it then it might be costly.  Also, Visual Studio Code should run on Chrome OS.  Visual Studio Code is a suped-up text editor with plugins.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install MAMP or XAMPP on your Chromebook. MAMP or XAMPP will turn your Chromebook into a web server capable of reading PHP.

EDITED:

Since you can't run MAMP or XAMPP on your Chromebook, then you should look into using a Cloud solution such as AWS or Google Cloud.

Comment: Neither of those software bundles have versions targetted at Chrome OS

Comment: Oh, I see... I wasn't aware of that.